# Backbone insert an App inside an App

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an app in backbone where I get data from a server and return me data about hotel.
Each hotel can contain many rooms (Single, double, triple..).
For this I have create two json
hotel.json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1", 
    "name": "Hotel1"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "2", 
    "name": "Hotel2"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "3", 
    "name": "Hotel3"
  }
]
```

rooms.json

```
[
    {
      "room" : [
        {
          "id" : "r1",
          "hotel_id" : "1",
          "name" : "Singola",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "room" : [
        {
          "id" : "r1_1",
          "hotel_id" : "1",
          "name" : "Doppia",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "room" : [
        {
          "id" : "r2",
          "hotel_id" : "2",
          "name" : "Singola",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "room" : [
        {
          "id" : "r2_1",
          "hotel_id" : "2",
          "name" : "Tripla",
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
```

In rooms.json there is a field called hotel_id to link rooms to its hotel.
Well this is my app in backbone to view hotel:

```
var Hotel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: function() {
                return {
                    name: 'HOTEL NAME',
                    star: '5'
                }
            }
        });

        var HotelsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Hotel,
            url: "includes/test-data.json",

            initialize: function(){
                console.log("Collection Hotel initialize");
            },

            parse: function(response){
                return(response);
            }     
        });

        var HotelView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
            template: _.template($("#hotel-list-template").html()),
            initialize: function(){ 
                this.collection = new HotelsCollection();
                this.collection.bind('sync', this.render, this);
                this.collection.fetch();
            },
            render: function(){
                console.log('Data hotel is fetched');
                var element = this.$el;
                element.html('');

                $(this.el).html(this.template({hotel: this.collection.models}));
            } 
        });
```

This is my template in uderscore:

```
<script type="text/template" id="hotel-list-template">
    <% _.each(hotel, function(name) { %> 
    <div id="hotel-container-<%= name.attributes.id %>">
        <p>Nome Hotel: <%= name.attributes.name %></p>
    </div>
    <% }); %>
    </script>
```

Now, how can I insert each room inside its hotel in the same div?
I thinked to make a classic model, a collection that fetch data but in the view in the render how can I tell to backbone to insert only room with hotel_id=1 to the div with id=hotel-container-1?

------------------UPDATE---------------------

```
var Hotel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: function() {
                return {
                    name: 'HOTEL NAME',
                    star: '5'
                }
            }
        });

        var HotelsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Hotel,
            url: "includes/test-data.json",

            initialize: function(){
                console.log("Collection Hotel initialize");
            },

            parse: function(response){
                return(response);
            },
            getRooms : function() {
                return _.map(allRooms.where({"hotel_id" : this.get("id")}), function(room) {
                    return room.toJSON();
                });
            },
            addRoom : function(room) {
                room.set("hotel_id", this.get("id"));
                allRooms.add(room);
            },
            // this will return Backbone´s native toJSON Object
            // with an extra field "rooms" which you can access
            toJSON : function() {
                var parent = Backbone.Collection.prototype.toJSON.call(this);
                return _.extend({}, parent, {rooms : this.getRooms().toJSON()});
            }
        });

        var HotelView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
            template: _.template($("#hotel-list-template").html()),
            initialize: function(){ 
                this.collection = new HotelsCollection();
                this.collection.bind('sync', this.render, this);
                this.collection.fetch();
            },
            render: function(){
                console.log('Data hotel is fetched');
                var viewModel = this.collection.toJSON();
                this.$el.html(this.template({models:viewModel}));

            } 
        }); 


var Room = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Rooms = Backbone.Collection.extend({model:Room});

var allRooms = new Rooms();

        var hotelView = new HotelView({ 
            el: $("#hotel") 
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I advise We add some changes to project architecture. **Firstly** We need to change `hotel` model like this:

```
{
    "id": "1", 
    "name": "Hotel1",
    "rooms": []
}
```

**Secondly** Model and Collection :

```
var Room = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Rooms = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Room,
    url : "rooms.json"
});
var Hotel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var HotelCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Hotel,
    url: "includes/test-data.json",
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Collection Hotel initialize");
    },

    parse: function(response) {
       response.rooms = new Rooms(response.rooms);
       return response;
    }    
});
```

**Third** View :

```
    var HotelView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
        template: _.template($("#hotel-list-template").html()),
        initialize: function(){ 
            this.collection = new HotelCollection();
            this.collection.bind('sync', this.render, this);
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
        render: function(){
            console.log('Data hotel is fetched');
            bindRoomToHotel();
            var element = this.$el;
            element.html('');

            $(this.el).html(this.template({hotel: this.collection.models}));
        },

        bindRoomToHotel: function() {
            allRooms = new Rooms();
            allRooms.fetch();
            _.each(this.collection.models, function(hotel) {
                 rooms = allRooms.where({'hotel_id' : hotel.id});
                 //
                 currentHotelRooms = hotel.get('rooms');
                 currentHotelRooms.add(rooms);
                 // or You can write like 
                 // hotel.get('rooms').add(rooms);
            }
        } 
    });
    var hotelView = new HotelView({ 
        el: $("#hotel") 
    });
```

I guess it is all. I hope it help You

Comment: I don't have understand your firts part, but if I use your code return me this error: Object [object Array] has no method 'add' . Can you please hel pme?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri,  I edited my answer, and I guess, it does not show error now

Comment: I have seen and accepted it to the right answer. thanks! +1 for the solution

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I am glad if I did something to help You

Answer (score 2):

first of all you are missing a Room Model and a Room Collection
Then, you should have an instance somewhere of all your Rooms.

```
var Room = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Rooms = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Room,
    url : "rooms.json"
});

var allRooms = new Rooms();
```

quite simple until here.

no you would create some methods for your hotel model, which would you enable some actions for your rooms

```
var Hotel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    getRooms : function() {
        return _.map(allRooms.where({"hotel_id" : this.get("id")}), function(room) {
            return room.toJSON();
        });
    },
    addRoom : function(room) {
        room.set("hotel_id", this.get("id"));
        allRooms.add(room);
    },
    // this will return Backbone´s native toJSON Object
    // with an extra field "rooms" which you can access
    toJSON : function() {
        var parent = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);
        return _.extend({}, parent, {rooms : this.getRooms().toJSON()});
    }
});
var HotelsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Hotel,
    url: "includes/test-data.json",
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Collection Hotel initialize");
    },
    parse: function(response){
        return(response);
    }

});
```

this is just a sample, you can do much more out of this.

now in your render function....

you can put anything to the underscores render method.

for example :

```
render : function() {
    //this will give you a nice formatted array (see toJSON override above)
    var viewModel = this.collection.toJSON();
    this.$el.html(this.template({models:viewModel});
}
```

In your View now, you have access to your "rooms" array...

```
<script type="text/template" id="hotel-list-template">
    <% _.each(models, function(hotel) { %> 
    <div id="hotel-container-<%= hotel.id %>">
        <p>Nome Hotel: <%= hotel.name %></p>
        <ul>
        <% _.each(hote.rooms, function(room) { %>
            <li><%=room.name%></li>
        <% }); %>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <% }); %>
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, not very clear, for example return me error into rendere, "cannot call method toJSON of undefined" I don't have understand what is hotels.

Comment: hotels is of course your "this.collection". I did not look at your naming conventions. In your case it would be "this.collection.toJSON()". Read the Docs of Backbone.Collection and Backbone.Model. there is toJSON described

Comment: sorry but i have right now no idea what you are exactly doing. But your error seems to me that you are having somewhere something different than I described

Comment: I have done like your example, but the part that doens't return me is where you load json of room. I thinked to put into RoomCOllection to parse it

Comment: please update your question with what you have right now. Or put your stuff into jsfiddle or jsbin so we can work it out

Comment: I see... ok there is a problem from me: you need to put getRooms and addRoom and toJSON into the "Hotel" Model, not the collection. But your problem with the error above I dont understand.

Comment: ok, moved and error Object [object Object] has no method 'map'

Comment: if you use Backbone, than you have underscore. if you have underscore, `_.map` MUST work

Comment: I haven't copied your update, i'm using backbone, now _map is ok.. but returns error: Object [object Array] has no method 'toJSON'

Comment: sorry i have no time to explain everything to you until it works for you. I was just making some examples how I would do it. But in the end you have to find it out by your self. The idea of how it should be done i posted here. It should help you to find the right solution. But you know, the final product and how it works finally, should be your work. You cannot just put here every single error you come up with. Try to google the error, read the documentation of the functions im using. Just try to do the same a normal developer does. Best greets luke. If you like my answer, please mark it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Room model, then a Rooms collection. Then you add rooms as property of HotelView. Then you call a fetch and use filter:

```
    var HotelView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
        template: _.template($("#hotel-list-template").html()),
        initialize: function(){ 
            this.collection = new HotelsCollection();
            this.collection.bind('sync', this.render, this);
            this.collection.fetch();

            this.rooms = new RoomsCollection();
            this.rooms.fetch();

            var self = this;
            this.rooms = this.rooms.filter(function(room){
                      return room.get("hotel_id") === self.get("id");
                })
         },
```

Then you just have to add the rooms to the div. You can create view for the rooms if your app is complex.

Here are the [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) of the filter function.

Edit: you create a template for one room. Then in the hotel template you put a empty div with #rooms id. Then for each room you [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the template in this div.

Comment: Ok until here I have understand well, but after how to add rooms to the div isn't clear how to do it. can you complete your answer please?

Comment: with your example I retrieve this.rooms empty